# JavaScript function that takes an array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that takes an array as a parameter and returns the first item in the array. This should work for an array of any size. Here is what I have so far, it appears to work just fine in the console but my instructor says there's a better way to do this:

```
var array = [];

function numbaOne(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[0])
    };
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've read about data structures and arrays but can't figure out how to simplify or make this better.

Comment: `return array[0];` that's all you need

Comment: may be your instructor is saying about foreach.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal NOT needed. OP is doing nothing in `for`.

Comment: What if the array has no elements in it?

Comment: you don't need a function for that, you can already use `array[0]` anywhere you can reach `array`...

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is looping over the array and printing out the first item each time. You just want:

```
var array = [...];

function numbaOne(array) {
    console.log(array[0]); // Print out the first value of the array
    return array[0]; // Return the first value of the array
}
```

There is one edge case here. If the array is empty, then the function will fail because `array[0]` will be `undefined`.
So, a more complete version might be:

```
var array = [...];

function numbaOne(array) {
    if(array.length > 0) { // Check if there is anything in the array
        console.log(array[0]);
        return array[0];
    } else { // If there isn't, let's return something "bad"
        console.log("The array is empty!");
        return undefined;
    }
}
```